# How could I manipulate data in a python list to modify and store?

Tags: python, list

I want to manipulate some data stored in a variable list and store it to a new variable in **python** :

oldvar =[]
newvar = []

values in oldvar in the format:

```
print(oldvar)

output:

[docker.xxx.com/service-1:2021.06.23-061151,docker.xxx.com/service-2:2021.06.28-052524,docker.xxx.com/service-3:2021.07.13-055424]
```

values in newvar expected to be in the format:

```
print(newvar)

output:

[service-1,service-2,service-3]
```

How can I read the data in the "**oldvar**" to modify it and store it as I mentioned in the output of "**newvar**"

Comment: For future reference note that you can (and should) use a limited version of markdown to format your questions (and answers) better. [Here's some formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.split` + list-comprehension:

```py
oldvar = [
    "docker.xxx.com/service-1:2021.06.23-061151",
    "docker.xxx.com/service-2:2021.06.28-052524",
    "docker.xxx.com/service-3:2021.07.13-055424",
]


newvar = [v.split("/")[-1].split(":")[0] for v in oldvar]
print(newvar)
```

Prints:

```py
['service-1', 'service-2', 'service-3']
```